# TypeInitialization Error when adding data to a List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Currently I am developing a C# WinForms application. And using `List<string>` to store data from a Class file. Here is my code for the static class file **UVS**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TMP_Server
{
    class UVS
    {
        public static List<string> SockUID = new List<string>(); //Var for saving client's Socket id and client ID
        public static List<string> MOGAlphaTyper = new List<string>(); //Var for storing Real-Time AlphaTyper client's ID
        public static List<string> MOGWordGame = new List<string>(); //Var for storing Real-Time WordGame (Antrakshari) client's ID
        public static List<string> RoomID = new List<string>();
        public static List<string>[] RID_GameData = new List<string>[1000000000];
    }
}
```

And below is my code for adding a string to MOGAlphaTyper List on button click from another Form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UVS.MOGAlphaTyper.Add("Sample Data"); //Boom here the exeption occurs
}
```

And this is the Exception Message :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'TMP_Server.UVS' threw an exception.'
Inner Exeption
OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

For you convenience I am attaching an Image file also of the exception.
[Exception Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FhAJ.png)

For additional troubleshooting I had done the followings:

When I created the `List<string>` in The same file(form1.cs) as my button code then on adding data no exception was thrown see below:

```
List<string> ListOfData = new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListOfData.Add("Sample Data"); //Now no exception occurs here
}
```

It seems to me that Class file (UVS.cs) or (static-constructor) is causing the issue.

What I want to achieve?

I only want to create a universal variable (Type-Of) which can be accessed from any form to transfer data from one form to another. I am also open to other solutions to this question.

I searched around on google and found nothing useful. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This line -> `RID_GameData = new List<string>[1000000000];` is causing the `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: OH! Thanks for the reply. It just solved my problem. Can you please explain me why is it causing this exception? and what is it's limit? BTW Thanks A Lot.

Comment: I don't know exactly what rules .NET has about memory allocation, but afaik it depends on the architecture you're building for and that array would require at least 4GB even before you start adding elements to it. I doubt you really need that much, how about using a `List<List<string>>` or some other collection that grows automatically?

Comment: Thanks A Lot for replying. I just understood the fact that you want to tell me.